# Как просмотреть исходный код?

Tags: html, javascript

Как просмотреть исходный код страницы после её динамичского изменения javascript'ом ?

Или построить качественное дерево динамичски-измененной html страницы ?

Comment: где то видел такой инструмент, сейчас поищу. а firebug не устраивает?

Comment: У IE точно был какой-то Live HTML.

Comment: F12 в хроме

Comment: Под FireFox есть [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/web-developer/). Нужный вам инструмент: **View Source > View Generated Source**

Comment: В Опере - Dragonfly по умолчанию стоит. Контекстное меню - проинспектировать элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FireFox - FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/)
[Chrome - FireBug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firebug-lite-for-google-c/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench)
[IE9 - FireBug](https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&q=firebug+ie9&spell=1&sa=X&ei=zgUxUZnFNaeL4ASWj4HICA&ved=0CC0QBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE&fp=39a3794fbc6ac6f8&biw=1600&bih=737)
удачного веб дева!